# Is Fuzzy Matching available in SQL Server 2019 Standard?

Tags: sql-server

I can't seem to find a definitive answer to what seems like it ought to be a really simple question. Previously fuzzy matching was an enterprise only feature, but I've heard it mentioned that this is now available with the standard edition. Can someone please confirm whether this is the case?

Edit: for clarity, I am specifically referring to SSIS fuzzy grouping / lookup

Comment: Can you link any documentation on the feature you're referring to? I've always previously implemented my own function for this. Unless you mean wildcard or RegEx matching, but that's always been available in all editions, so I doubt you mean that.

Comment: Could be referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/data-quality-services/data-matching - but that is only a guess. @danisthirty, you should edit the question to be more specific about what you are looking for. Better still also add what you are trying to achieve with it, as there might be ways to do the same job with other features.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the OP to add that I'm looking at SSIS fuzzy grouping / lookup functionality

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571974/why-can-i-run-ssis-fuzzy-grouping-from-visual-studio-but-not-the-deployed-packag seems to confirm that it's an Enterprise only feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuzzy Matching is still enterprise only

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15